# create multiindex from dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to create the multi-index dataframe from following dataframe:

```
               date_time                   session
              2015-07-30 10:32:54.000        1
              2015-07-30 10:32:54.000        1
              2015-07-30 10:36:39.000        1            
              2015-07-30 10:36:39.000        1
             ........................        1
              2015-07-30 11:58:57.000        2
              2015-07-30 12:18:37.000        2
              2015-07-30 12:28:51.000        2
```

to obtain smth like:

```
        date_time                   session
      2015-07-30 10:32:54.000        1
      2015-07-30 10:32:54.000        
      2015-07-30 10:36:39.000                   
      2015-07-30 10:36:39.000        
     ........................        
      2015-07-30 11:58:57.000        2
      2015-07-30 12:18:37.000        
      2015-07-30 12:28:51.000        
      .......................        3
```

guiding by the answers for this question:
[MultiIndex Group By in Pandas Data Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214985/multiindex-group-by-in-pandas-data-frame)

I tried this code for my data:

```
def create_multi():
    multi=df.set_index(['session', 'date'], inplace=True)
    print multi
```

but it returns  `None`
I don't know if this method is appropriate for what I need to do and I just use it not correctly, or I should use another method

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You passed `inplace=True` so it's performed inplace so returns nothing when you assigned to `multi`.

```
def create_multi():
    multi=df.set_index(['session', 'date'], inplace=False)
    print multi
```

The above would work, check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index), note that the default is `inplace=False` so it's strictly not necessary to specify if you want that behaviour